# Regex in Java: Match alphanumeric between punctuation characters

Tags: java, regex

**I'm working on a text cleaner method**

*My situation is that I receive a plain text from a search in the wikimedia api. This text usually comes along with links represented as plain text*

For example:

> The Sevilla Tower (Spanish: Torre Sevilla), known until 2015 as the Pelli Tower, is an office skyscraper in Seville, Spain. Its construction started in March 2008 and was completed in 2015. The tower is 180.5 metres (592 ft) tall and has 40 floors. It is an office building, with the entrance to the tower located off Odiel street. The tower is the tallest building in Andalusia and in the city of Seville, and the seventh tallest in Spain. It provides a panoramic view on all Seville. The tower is located in La Cartuja, the former zone of the Universal Exposition that took place in Seville between April and October 1992. It is located next to the river in an area being redeveloped since the early 2000s. The tower is flanked by two four story podium buildings also designed by César Pelli. The curved edges of the podium buildings define a plaza that opens on the north and south and narrows at the center, creating a pedestrian-scaled commercial street.The tower notably hosts a 5-star hotel, Eurostars Torre Sevilla, along with various offices. == Controversy == It had been reported that UNESCO was considering putting the Seville's monuments which are classified as World Heritage Sites (the Cathedral, Alcazar and Archivo de Indias) into the "Threatened List", because of the tower's ?negative visual impact? on the old town skyline of Seville. UNESCO went so far as to ask the city to reduce the tower's height, but city officials ignored the requests. The proposal was rejected at the meeting of the UNESCO World Heritage Committee in Saint Petersburg in 2012 but the meeting regretted that work on the tower had not been suspended, as requested by the Committee at its previous session, and that no discussions or consultations had been undertaken to consider how the project could be improved and any possible impact further reduced. == References == == External links == Sevillasemueve Sevilla21.com Factoría Urbana Ayuntamiento de Sevilla

As you can see the text is fairly readable, but there is some "=" or "?" between there that is meant to represent the hyperlinks to other wiki pages *(thing I'm not interested in)*.

### What I have tried so far:

Erase the "=" and "?" chars with `text.replace('=','');` and `text.replace('?','');`, but I know that there has to be a regex for this.

I thought:

```java
text.replaceAll("[=+[a-zA-z0-9]+=+]?","");
```

But for the previous text that returns:

> (: ), , , . . . ( ) . , . , . . , . . é . , - . - , , . ' ( , ) " ", ' ? ? . ' , . , , . . í

I have very few knowledge of regex patterns, so **how is a regex that matches "==Alphanumeric and punctuation=="?**

Comment: You can't nest square brackets in regex - that regex you had is wrong

Comment: Do you mean like this perhaps? `(==|\?)\h*\w+(?:\h+\w+)*\h*\1`  https://regex101.com/r/oRKvW4/1 or a bit broader match `(==|\?).*?\1`

Comment: You wrote: _I have very few knowledge of regex patterns_ Did you try the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either `==` or a question mark in a capturing group, and use a backreference to group 1 using `\1`

You can use the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or extend it to use `\w` (Note to use **A-Z** instead of A-z)

```
(==|\?)\h*\w+(?:\h+\w+)*\h*\1
```

- `(==|\?)` Capture group 1, match either `==` or `?`
- `\h*` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:\h+\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching the horizontal whitespace chars and word chars
- `\h*` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\1` Backreference to group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oRKvW4/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "(==|\\?)\\h*\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)*\\h*\\1";
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex `(== [A-Za-z0-9 _,.?!"'\-]+ ==)|(\?[A-Za-z0-9 _,.?!"'\-]+\?)` matches alphanumeric characters and punctuation between 2 equal signs (and a space too) *or* 2 question marks (without spaces). You may add other characters between the square brackets if you wish (for example, ">").

`[A-Za-z0-9 _,.?!"'\-]` matches letters, numbers, underscores, commas, periods, question marks, exclamation marks, double quotes, single quotes, and hyphens.

Link to online regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/aqUtfn/2

EDIT: Another way to do it (I changed the answer by 'the fourth bird' around a bit to make it more strict) - `(==|\?)((?<!\?)\s)?[[A-Za-z:;?!,."'][A-Za-z :;?!,."']+?\2?\1`.

This will still match the stuff above (2 equal signs, a space, alphanumeric characters and punctuation, a space, and 2 more equal signs *or* a question mark, alphanumeric characters and punctuation, and another question mark), but uses backreferences to do it.

Link to online regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/aqUtfn/4

Comment: The second 'more strict' pattern will not match if this `== External links ==` is at the end because it has to match `\2\1` where `\2` is the whitespace char followed by `\1` which is `==` followed by another whitespace char. It also does not match `?negative visual impact?` as there is no `\2`

Comment: @Thefourthbird You're right, I think I've fixed it now, but now it's just a mess :(